# Grails XMPP Chat Website

Tags: grails, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I'm trying to create a chat website using the Smack library and Openfire. My problem is that when I log in with a second user, the first user gets overwritten. I don't understand why. When I log in I create a new connection, then save that connection in a map, where the key is an ID from my local database(from user table). So when I log in with a second user, it should create a new connection, the saving that connection to the map, with a different key, then the first one. When I create a new connection, I also start a new thread. So why does the first user's connection gets overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Spring Social Facebook plugin? I had the same problem with Grails 2.1. I resolved it by upgrading to 2.2.3.

Comment: I am using grails 2.2.3. This problem was solved, by using:

'def currentRequest = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes'

and in the currentRequest I save the loged in user's information like this: 'currentRequest["something] = ...userinfo...'

Now I have another problem: I have a class that contains the loged in user's information, and in that class I have a few listeners: message listener, etc. They all work fine, except for one: the invitation listener, which listens if I have an invitation to a group chat or not. This listener sometimes works and sometimes doesn't...